# Bitmap loses quality when stretched/shrinked on buttons background

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

### INTRODUCTION AND RELEVANT INFORMATION:

I have an owner drawn static control.

It should have bitmap on top of a gradient background.

Static controls dimensions **are not fixed**, they are calculated during the creation of parent window.

I load a bitmap with background color of RGB( 255, 163, 94 ) from resource file.

Using `TransparentBlt( ... , RGB( 255, 163, 94 ) )` API I stretch/shrink bitmap to fit the static controls client area ( bitmap is Device Dependant Bitmap, not a DIB, if that matters  ).

Bitmap picture has both horizontal and vertical resolution 150 DPI, 24 color bit depth, width 4395 pixels, and height 5613 pixels.

Bitmap is loaded via `LoadBitmap( ... )` API on `WM_CREATE`.

The original picture is bellow, but I have reduced its size, so I can upload it:

[image]

### THE PROBLEM:

The problem is in quality of the picture.

Bellow is the result I get after owner drawing the static control:

[image]

The *pixelation* is obvious.

Aspect ratio is lost as well, since I use `TransparentBlt()`.

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM:

Browsing through SO archive, I have found similar questions, but they were related to Android. None of them helped me. Maybe my inexperience prevents me to see useful information.

Following one link from those questions I have learned about existence of image scaling algorithms. This is the page I have in mind: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28bitmap%29

I have tried to use smaller bitmap, but picture is then blurry, even though I resolve *pixelation* to some point.

It seems that my problem lies in insufficient, or to much, data in bitmap so when I try to "push" large bitmap into small button, it just can't fit so I get *pixelation* and *jagged* effects, yet If I try to put small bitmap into big button, then data is missing which results in a blurry picture.

After browsing through Internet, I have seen advices and suggestions that this can be solved with vector graphics and meta files.

Since I am dumbstruck by this, I will ask several questions.

**If the topic is broad then I ask the community to inform me of it through comments, and I will remove it and will try to rephrase it to fit the SO rules of posting questions better.**

### QUESTIONS:

This problem really happened unexpected to me, so I do not know how to start solving it, since I am fairly new to WIN32.

I must admit I am shocked, since I have expected that `TransparentBlt()` would do all the work for me.

How can I solve this problem, so I can keep aspect ratio and quality of the picture ?

I will consider the following solutions:

1. Combining certain GDI API calls into my existing handler for stretching/shrinking, so I can achieve high quality and preserve aspect ratio of the picture, without modifying the code too much ?
2. Using GDI+ to solve my problem. I haven't used GDI+ so far, but one has to start some day, why not now, if that is what will solve my problems ?
3. If vector graphics can solve my problem I must URGE the community to do me the following favor: ANY recommendation of book/tutorial/documentation/article/code example on Vector Graphics in PURE WIN32 would be greatly appreciated, since I myself haven't found any.
4. If I must implement one of the scaling algorithms please recommend some books/tutorials/links/code example, since I myself haven't found any.

**I can't use libraries, it is the restriction imposed upon me**, however, if the solution is acceptable **and can be implemented fast**, I could try to convince my employers to loosen their criteria, so libraries can be used.

If my criteria to preserve **both** aspect ratio and quality of the picture is too much, I will choose the **quality of the picture** then. I can always post a new question about aspect ratio, and maybe I will find a solution myself in the meanwhile.

That would be all. Thank you for your patience and time.

Regards.

Comment: You can solve the aspect ratio problem by resizing the bitmap some other way and then calling `TransparentBlt` to put the result on your control. The quality issue is, in general, not easily solvable because when you shrink an image you're losing information. The hard part is determining *which* information to lose. But resizing and then blitting might be good enough.

Comment: Graphics with fine lines like that just don't scale well, particularly if you scale down and don't use a good bi-cubic interpolation filter.  Don't scale it.

Comment: @JimMischel,Can you provide some links to pseudo code/code example/books/articles? Your comment is a bit vague to me, since I am inexperienced, so I could use a little "nudge". If more code is needed to be posted, I will do it. Thank you for your comment. Regards.

Comment: Resize by creating an in-memory DC, selecting a new bitmap into it, and then calling [StretchBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145120(v=vs.85).aspx) to with your source and destination bitmaps. Then blit that new image using `TransparentBlt`. That may very well do what you need. It's been a long time since I worked with raw Windows bitmaps. I do know, though, that there examples available of what I describe. A little time with a search engine will locate them.

Comment: Thank you for a swift reply, I will employ search engine, hopefully something pops out. Regards.

Comment: @HansPassant, That is some bad news, I fear, as the static control is in the main window. That is why I must scale it. Being more experienced colleague than I am, I ask you to reconsider your answer, and try to help me by taking these information into account. I would really appreciate if you could find some small amount of time to point me in the right direction. Thank you for your comment, I appreciate. Regards.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to clip the image instead of resizing it?  Otherwise, to minimize information loss, you may want to look at converting the bitmap to a metafile ([AutoTrace](http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/) seems to do a pretty decent job), and then play the metafile.

Comment: I have never used metafiles, though in his book Programing Windows( 5th edition ) Charles Petzold writes about them. Maybe with your help, Google and Petzold's book, I could pull that off. So yes, I am interested in using metafiles. The only problem is that I can't use libraries at this moment, but maybe we can work something out. I could always ask another question and use Google. Can you be more specific about clipping the image? I haven't understood that part entirely? Thank you. Regards.

Comment: You might find the [CopyImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648031(VS.85).aspx) function useful.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff, by "clip", I mean is it allowable to only draw a portion of the image if the static control is too small?  Because the only way to not lose detail with a bitmap is to clip it; any resizing will result in loss of detail.

Comment: Unfortunately, I must place the whole bitmap in the static control as in the second picture above. That is why I am interested in your suggestion to use metafile. Hopefully you are interested to help, and we might pull it off. Regards.

Comment: @JimMischel, I have made a small test program, to test some of your suggestions. These are my results: After setting stretch mode to `BLACKONWHITE`, and call `StretchBlt`, the image gets drastically sharper. I have tried simple double buffering to do this, so there is no flicker, and was able to handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` properly. I just do not know how to perform `TransparentBlt()`-ing. Can you please try to suggest some pseudo code or instructions on how to do it? Sorry for disturbing, but my search engine returns links to tutorials that do the very basic of double buffering.Thank you. Regards.

Comment: A typical problem with bitmap stretching is not enabling best stretching quality, which need you to call [`SetStretchBltMode(..., HALFTONE)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before actual `StretchBlt`. The same supposedly applies to `TransparentBlt`.

Comment: @RomanR., I do not understand your comment. Can you please clarify? Because, the only way for me to get sharp image was to use `BLACKONWHITE`, if I use `HALFTONE`, the picture blurs.

Comment: You want the following sequence of calls: `INT x = SetStretchBltMode(..., HALFTONE); TransparentBlt(...); SetStretchBltMode(..., x); ` So that `HALFTONE` mode applies to your stretching. Some blurring is inevitable because the image in question is raster, not vector, however halftoning avoid obvious pixelation caused by loss in continuity of fine lines.

Comment: @RomanR., I have tried your suggested sequence, but I still get the same quality. Thank you for your suggestion. Any other ideas?

Comment: Also, since you already doing relatively low level GDI painting, to get fine lines over stretched map you might consider painting them directly using `Polyline` and friends. You will be able to scale points prior to painting the accurate line.

Comment: Using `PolyLine` like the way you have described is new to me, since I am not that experienced in Win32. Can you provide links to code examples/tutorials or some books? Or maybe a small snippet? I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have "battled" this problem for nearly three months, and after all that research I must admit that *Mr.Passant* was right-crisp images like the one above will simply lose on quality when scaled.

Therefore, I have decided to use vector graphics.

Maybe I will use `Enhanced Windows Metafile`s or will try with some library for `SVG`.

I hereby thank to everyone trying to help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

Since the target size is less than the image's original size, GDI just leaves out certain pixels. This is efficient but the results are often poor quality. To do this better, you need to enable anti-aliasing. With anti-aliasing enabled, pixels that are too much are not just dropped, but merged (averaged) together with adjacent pixels.

In GDI you basically have to call

```
SetStretchBltMode (HALFTONE);
```

before calling StretchBlt/TransparentBlt to achieve an anti-aliased effect.

EDIT: I think I remember that TransparentBlt ignores the StretchBltMode. If this is true, you'll have to do without transparency. Possible solution: Create a memory DC that's as large as your original image, draw the background, render the image on top using TransparentBlt. Later, use StretchBlt to draw the image from the mem DC to the screen.